# why do i need to include <vector> to use them?

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ and trying to figure out how to use `vector`.

More specifically, I want to know when I need to use `#include<vector>`. I am asking that because I have seen programs with and without the `#include` statement that use `vector` in the program.

Comment: Well, that's the way c++ works. You have to include the header files to get the declarations for what you're using.

Comment: If you use something from a standard header then include that header.  Makes life nice and easy if you follow that behavior.

Comment: If you use the `#include` directive on a file then that's basically the same as dropping the whole contents of that referenced file into your source. Thus if the file you reference has it's own includes those files will also be put into your source.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please write _answers_ in the _answer section_. That's the way SE works.

Comment: I know the meaning of #include, my question is if you need to include<vector> if you want to use vector so how its possible that you also can use vector without to include it?

Comment: In English, the word "I" is capitalised, Nadavp.

Comment: @Nadavp In such case it was already included from another header file.

Comment: @Nadavp *I know the meaning of #include* --If you knew the meaning of `#include`, then the answer should have been obvious to you.  There is another `#include` that included `<vector>` within the chain of include files.

Answer (score 11):

When you see code that uses `std::vector`, but did not `#include <vector>`, **that code is broken**. Period.

It may "just so happen" to work on particular compilers/standard library implementations/platforms/planets, depending on which other standard headers "just so happen" to already be including `<vector>` for their own use. This shall not be relied upon.

Comment: In other words, C++ (even C++17) does not have modules yet.

Comment: You forgot to add it might work on Tuesdays but not the other days  :) :)

Comment: ok thank you. Further to your answer, how can i know that `vector` is part of std? i mean, how can i know in future that I need to add `std::` before some component in my code?

Comment: @Nadavp: If it comes with C++, it's `std::`. When in doubt, Google it.

Comment: `#if _HAS_CXX17`:- `<vector>` is also included in `<filesystem>`, along with fav goodies like `<algorithm>` and `<utility>`.

Answer (score 8):

`vector` is not actually built into C++, it is only part of its standard library which is guaranteed to be available to you if you use C++. `vector` (or, by its full name, `std::vector`) is itself implemented in C++.

By writing `#include <vector>`, you are telling the compiler to not only use your own code, but to also compile a file called `vector`. This file is actually somewhere on your harddrive (if you use GNU/Linux, it's probably located at `/usr/include/c++/[GCC_VERSION]/vector`).

You cannot use `std::vector` without including that file, because the compiler then doesn't know a class called `std::vector`. The compiler only knows the *language* C++, not its standard library!

If some programs use `std::vector` without including its header file, it's because some header file that they have already included, has an `#include <vector>` somewhere. There may be good reasons for that (e.g. some C++ courses ship with a file that includes all necessary headers and that is used in the first few lessons). However there may also be standard library headers that include `vector` (some implementations of `iostream` do that). Relying upon that is not a good idea because it differs from implementation to implementation, so your program might work in Visual C++ 2010, but it doesn't compile on GNU or in a newer version of Visual C++.

Answer (score 4):

You may see code that does not `#include <vector>` *directly*. But if you inspect the preprocessed code I'm certain you'll find that that code *did* include the header - but indirectly through some other header.

This is fragile and you shouldn't do it. But that doesn't mean it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the header file, to use any type of data/function. All the data types and functions in c++ are included in their own libraries.If you dont include the library, the c++ program won't know what you used, because it doesnt know they even excist.Its like :

> You want to play with Jim's dog, but you dont know who Jim is, or what
>   a dog is.